# Disable http calls over proxy , or rooted devices

Tags: android, proxy, retrofit, okhttp

> ```
>       final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
>             .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
>             .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
>                 @Override
>                 public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
>                     Request.Builder ongoing = chain.request().newBuilder();
>                     ongoing.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
>                     ongoing.addHeader("User-Agent", System.getProperty("http.agent"));
>                     return chain.proceed(ongoing.build());
>                 }
>             })
>             .connectTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
>             .build();
>         Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
>                 .baseUrl(globalUrl())
>                 .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
>                 .client(okHttpClient)
>                 .build();
> ```

So basically, am doing that in my android code. However, if a device is rooted or am using proxy ( steps below) the url is still being submitted and working.How can I disable under such measures the calls.

```
1 - Connect to WIFI network (e.g. 'Alex')
2 - Settings->WIFI
3 - Long tap on connected network's name (e.g. on 'Alex')
4 - Modify network config-> Show advanced options
5 - Set proxy settings
```

Answer (score 2):

Manually configure NO_PROXY as your proxy in OkHttpClient.Builder. It’s an option on java.net.Proxy.

Comment: I implemented that, final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .proxy(Proxy.NO_PROXY) However the url call still works but not using proxy. I like to disable it all together.